# Dynamically add a route in a Nuxt3 middleware

Tags: vue.js, routes, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxt3

I have a Nuxt3 project where I'd like to add new routes based on an API call to a database. For example, let's say a user navigates to `/my-product-1`. A route middleware will look into the database and if it finds an entry, it will return that a `product` page should be rendered (instead of a category page, for example).

This is what I came up with:

```js
export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {

    const router = useRouter()

    addRouteMiddleware('routing', async (to) => {
        if (to.path == '/my-awesome-product') {
            router.addRoute({
                component: () => import('/pages/product.vue'),
                name: to.path,
                path: to.path
            })
            
            console.log(router.hasRoute(to.path))   // returns TRUE
        }
    }, { global: true })

})
```

To keep it simple, I excluded the API call from this example. The solution above works, but not on initial load of the route. The route is indeed added to the Vue Router (even on the first visit), however, when I go directly to that route, it shows a 404 and only if I don't reload the page on the client does it show the correct page when navigated to it for the second time.

I guess it has something to do with the router not being updated... I found the following example in a GitHub issue, however, I can't get it to work in Nuxt3 as (as far as I'm aware) it doesn't provide the `next()` method.
When I tried adding `router.replace(to.path)` below the `router.addRoute` line, I ended up in an infinite redirect loop.

```js
// from https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/3660
// You need to trigger a redirect to resolve again so it includes the newly added

route:
let hasAdded = false;
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (!hasAdded && to.path === "/route3") {
    router.addRoute(
      {
        path: "/route3",
        name: "route3",
        component: () => import("@/views/Route3.vue")
      }
    );
    hasAdded = true;
    next('/route3');
    return;
  }
  next();
});
```

How could I fix this issue, please?

Edit:
Based on a suggestion, I tried using `navigateTo()` as a replacement for the `next()` method from Vue Router. This, however, also doesn't work on the first navigation to the route.

```
let dynamicPages: { path: string, type: string }[] = []

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, _from) => {
    const router = useRouter()

    router.addRoute({
        path: to.path,
        name: to.path,
        component: () => import ('/pages/[[dynamic]]/product.vue')
    })
    
    if (!dynamicPages.some(route => route.path === to.path)) {
        dynamicPages.push({
            path: to.path,
            type: 'product'
        })
        return navigateTo(to.fullPath)
    }
})
```

I also came up with this code (which works like I wanted), however, I don't know whether it is the best solution.

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {

    const router = useRouter()
    
    let routes = []

    router.beforeEach(async (to, _from, next) => {

        const pageType = await getPageType(to.path) // api call
        
        if (isDynamicPage(pageType)) {
            router.addRoute({
                path: to.path,
                name: to.path,
                component: () => import(`/pages/[[dynamic]]/product.vue`),
            })
            
            if (!routes.some(route => route.path === to.path)) {
                routes.push({
                    path: to.path,
                    type: pageType,
                })
                next(to.fullPath)
                return
            }
        }
        
        next()
    })
})
```

Comment: did you get this to work? i've tried the code you say work with defineNuxtPlugin and adding a router.beforeEach but all i do is end up in a recursion nightmare.

Comment: @Henriksjodahl yes I did, if you check whether the route is already added and add a flag like `bypassFetch` not to fetch the route for the second time after calling `next()`, it works fine

Comment: would you mind taking a peek at this solution because i just cant get it to work https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-1cetba-sn9iac?file=plugins%2FdynamicRouting.ts

Comment: @Henriksjodahl Seems that they either changed the behaviour or there is a bug in `Nuxt 3.4.2`  Either way, here is a working version, which is identical to what I'm using in `Nuxt 3.2.2`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-1cetba-3jds35?file=plugins/dynamicRouting.ts

In the newer version, the vue router seems to forget the route...
If you thik it's a bug too, would you mind for creating an issue in the Nuxt github repo, please?

Comment: Thank you! i thought i was loosing my mind :) I will try to open an issue in github

Comment: Opened issue in github: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/20491

Comment: @Henriksjodahl You're welcome, glad we figured out where the problem was. 
I would be losing my mind as well if I updated Nuxt just like I wanted to today 

If you come up with a better way to handle the dynamic routes, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on resolving method called before each route change, the Nuxt's replacement for `next()` method you're looking for is `navigateTo`
https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/navigate-to

And I advise you to use route middleware and put your logic into `/middleware/routeGuard.global.ts`. It will be auto-executed upon every route resolving event. The file will contain:

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {

  // your route-resolving logic you wanna perform

  if ( /* navigation should happen */ {
    return navigateTo( /* your dynamic route */ )
  }
  // otherwise do nothing - code will flow and given to.path route will be resolved
})
```

**EDIT: However, this would still need content inside `/pages` directory or some routes created via Vue Router. Because otherwise `navigateTo` will fail, as there would be no route to go.**

Here is an example of one possible approach:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-8wz4sj

Based on `pageType` returned from API Nuxt route guard can dynamically re-route the original URL to a specific slug page.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use dynamic routing within `/page` directory structure - https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/pages#dynamic-routes

The [slug] concept is designed exactly for your usecase. You don't need to know all possible routes in advance. You just provide a placeholder and Nuxt will take care of resolving during runtime.

Comment: I am aware of this approach, however, I do not want to add everything into a single `[...slug].vue` catch-all file with multiple v-if(s).

Comment: I posted alternative solution then. But I still think you can achieve a lot with `/pages` directory itself. There doesn't have to be only one dumb "catch-all" slug, you can combine it on both page and subfolder level - https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/pages#example - you have simple access to route params, you can pass them as props into components... Also there are layouts, that help you have common code together and dynamcially render only part of the actual page - https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/layouts - this can also solve a thing or two.

Comment: Thank you. I tried out the other solution (as you can see in the updated question) however, it doesn't seem to solve my problem. I already tried using `navigateTo()` before creating this post... maybe I'm doing something wrong.

I was able to come up with a solution, however, I'm not sure, whether it's a good one or not. - Basically using the VueRouter directly  What do you think about it?

Comment: I just realized it cannot work as I intended, because you'd still need a counterpart in `/pages` structure in order `navigateTo()` knows how to resolve the given parameter...sorry for misleading you :(

Comment: I love Nuxt becaude it hides Vue stuff from me and does all the tedious component registering and routing automatically. To me it feels kinda wrong, you're throwing it away. On the other hand - if it works, then it is probably a good enough solution. I may only dispute your belief, that you cannot solve your use-case with dynamic `/pages`. Maybe if we go back to the begininning and discuss a bit more, what is your goal? And where you see limits of using `[slugs]`?

Comment: I love the abstractions that Nuxt 3 does as well! I haven't really seen such a great DX anywhere else and they keep coming up with new improvements I haven't even thought I needed. I didn't wanna throw away the "nuxt router"... and I don't feel like I'm losing anything with this approach. The `vue` files in the pages directory will get matched first, so I did not throw away anything. Only if there is no match will it call an api endpoint to check what type of page it is - and if even that doesn't know the page, it gives a 404.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to have let's say `/blue-tshirt-with-stripes` route show a product page and then for example `/cotton-tshirts` show a product category with a list of products. I don't want to have `/product/blue-tshirt-with-stripes` or `/category/cotton-tshirts` because of SEO. As far as I'm aware, I would have to create a catch-all `[...slug].vue` file in the `pages` dir and check what type of page it is there (the page type will come from a laravel backend) - and have multiple "page" components with `v-if="type === 'product'"` etc.

Comment: What do you think of this - https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-8wz4sj ? Route guard would check for the fetched pageType and decide where to re-route towards prepared /pages structure. And if the possible values of "pageType" would match the folders, there wouldn't even be any if-else logic - you'll just take it and just place it before seo-friendly link

Comment: Yeah, this is something I've tried before creating this post as well. As I found out, it is not something that would solve the SEO problem. I used `/category/` just as an example, in reality, it would be a category name. The same product could belong to more than one category & this approach would result in different URLs leading to the same page, which is not very good for SEO. (afaik)
But thank you for the example nonetheless, someone else might be looking for exactly this.